# Are Google Play Services Supported on Android Things?

Tags: android, google-play, google-nearby, android-things

I'm developing an app for Android Things and want to use Nearby from Google Play Services to communicate with my IoT device across Android and iOS.

I've compiled the app, but am getting a message that it's not supported on my device, however, the Android Things website clearly states that there is support for it.

I'm using the sample code provided by Google here with no modifications other than adding my API key https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/messages/NearbyDevices.

My device is a Raspberry Pi 3 model B and I'm using the latest release of Android Things.

Comment: Perhaps it is not available on all Things-capable hardware.

Comment: show us some code so we can try to recreate your problem

Comment: You need to provide more details. Several developers are using Nearby successfully on Android Things, so we need to know your code and errors to address the specific problem you are facing.

Comment: I just updated to Android Things Dev Preview 0.4 and am getting this same message when my app launches. For those commenters who say they've got it running, what version of Android Things are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I updated the sample code to use Play Services version 10.0.0. Everything works now!

Comment: I've run into the same problem you described. I've got `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.2.4'` in my application but I'm getting that compatibility warning. Thoughts?

Comment: What does the rest of your gradle file have? Also, make sure that you have the latest developer preview.

Comment: Well I changed it to exactly 10.0.0, but I'm still getting the error. I'm using Android Things Dev Preview 0.4, which is the latest. Given the timing that you posted your question, I think the latest at the time was AT 0.3. My app/build.gradle file is [here](https://gist.github.com/soapergem/3c0e5adeba3d80257d6f3707798a273f). I've tried to do exactly what you did: use the sample project with as few modifications as possible. The only changes I made were updating the play-services-nearby dependency version, and add my API key to the manifest. It does work on my phone but not on the Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

Try using google services version as 11.0.2
It worked for me 
If we specify a higher version it asks us to update
So in the gradle file in dependencies 
change

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:X.X.X'
>   where X.X.X is your version to 
>   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

Play services (and Firebase) is supported (to some degree) by Android Things.  It doesn't self-update like it does on normal Android devices.  When you develop against a version of Android Things, you should understand which version of Play services you're working with, so you can use the correct version of the client libraries.

You can find out the version of Play services on the [release notes page](https://developer.android.com/things/versions/releases).  You can find out which parts of Play services and Firebase are supported [on this page](https://developer.android.com/things/versions/things-1.0-changes#google-services).